# Google Spreasheet Script : for each row, automatically fill cell if other cell is

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm managing my bank accounts with a Google Spreasheet. I have an "Operations" spr. where I copy paste my operations (from downloaded extracts of accounts).
Then I tag them : TYPE ("one-time" or "regular"), CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY.
I'd like to automatically fill as much cells as possible thanks to the LABEL of the operations. 
That would be something like :

```
browse rows where TYPE is undefined
   if label is like '%...%'
      then TYPE="..."; CATEGORY="..."; SUBCATEGORY="..."
   if label is like '%...%'
      then TYPE="..."; CATEGORY="..."; SUBCATEGORY="..."
   and so on...
```

It seems I have the "if" condition right for a single row (but I don't know how to have a "like" operator), but I don't succeed with the loop on empty-TYPE rows.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Opérations');
  if (ss.getRange('E106').getValue() == 'PRLV SEPA AVIVA VIE'){
      ss.getRange('I106').setValue('Récurrent');
      ss.getRange('J106').setValue('Logement');
      ss.getRange('K106').setValue('Log-Assurance prêt');
   }
```

Could someone help me with my issue ? 
Thanks a lot, best regards, 
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

I worked on my script and finally got something that is working :

```
        function preRemplissageAuto() {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Opérations');

          for (var i = 2; i < ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
            var type = ss.getRange('I'+i);
            if (type.getValue() == ''){ 
              var libelle = ss.getRange('E'+i).getValue();
              var categ = ss.getRange('J'+i);
              var sscateg = ss.getRange('K'+i);
              var commentaire = ss.getRange('L'+i);
              var log = ss.getRange('M'+i);

              if (ss.getRange('E'+i).getValue() == 'PRLV SEPA SOGESSUR') {type.setValue('Récurrent');categ.setValue('Assurances');sscateg.setValue('A-Habitation');log.setValue('Remplissage auto');      } 
              if (ss.getRange('E'+i).getValue() == 'PRLV SEPA MAIF 79038 NIORT CEDEX') {type.setValue('Récurrent');categ.setValue('Assurances');sscateg.setValue('A-MAIF');log.setValue('Remplissage auto');      } 
              if (ss.getRange('E'+i).getValue() == 'PRLV SEPA MGEN 112') {type.setValue('Récurrent');categ.setValue('Assurances');sscateg.setValue('A-MGEN');log.setValue('Remplissage auto');}      
              //etc, lots of "if"
          }
        }
```

The script is working.
I have around 1000 lines for now, but the "Type" (for the "if" condition) is blank on around 100 lines max. I had an "execution delay timed out" the first time I ran it, and got the following advice on the bulb icon : 
(rough translation from french ;-))

> The Range.getValue method is very used by this script. 
>   The script uses a method considered as expensive. Each call generate a long-time
>   call to a distant server. This can have a critical impact on the
>   script's running time. in particular on large data. If the script has
>   performance issue, we recommend you to use another method, for example
>   Range.getValues().

Does someone has an advice to optimize my script ? (Using the recommended method or not)

Thanks for your help, have a nice day !

Guillaume